# Meteor: add extra data to user on social sign up

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

In Meteor, I'd like to add a `referrer` field to new user signups. I can do this for users that register with a password, by passing in extra options to be used with `Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user)`.

But this doesn't seem to work with social login. Any ideas how I can get this working?

Comment: `Accounts.onCreateUser` will be called for even social logins, try to add console log at the start of the callback

Comment: I just tested in my local and it works for me

Comment: Passing in extra options doesn't work. I did try this before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I had a similar issue, and ended doing something like

- create the user without the field you would like to pass as an option
- ask the client for the value of that field
- update the user

So:

```
//server
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  if (user.services.facebook)
    user.askReferer = true;
  retur user;
});

//client
var userId;
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  var user = Meteor.user();
  if (!user || user.id === userId || !user.askReferer) {return;}
  userId = user.id;
  var referer = ...;
  Users.update({_id: user.id}, {$set: {referer: referer}}, {$unset: {askReferer: 1}});
});
```

Would love if someone comes up with a better solution!

Comment: if it's a referrer, then it should be from a click on a URL and the url should contain a unique token. Then your app can catch that token before forwarding the user to signin and add the field on login.

Comment: Yes. That's how things should work, but it's hard to add that field to the user profile when using social login. That's what I'm trying to figure out how to do.

Comment: I think the difficulty is to add fields on login through social media

Comment: Thanks @Guig. Ended up using your solution in the package. Would love to find a cleaner solution still

Comment: Sure, feel free to update the answer if a better one comes along